# The scalability of the composite pattern when generics are used

Tags: java, generics, composition

Imagine the following object hierarchy of types:

```
Group
  Person
    Address
```

And then some class implementations:

```
ImmutableGroup
  PeopleyPerson
  MonsterPerson
    PostalAddress
      getZip() :: String
    EmailAddress
      getDomain() :: String
```

We want to allow clients of this API to use the types in a typesafe manner. So a client may want to do:

```
group.personAt(0).getAddress().getDomain()
```

And they can do that because Group is defined as:

```
Group<? extends PeopleyPerson<EmailAddress>> group
```

This means Group has to be defined as:

```
interface Group<A extends Address,P extends Person<A>>
```

We've had to make Group aware of Address even though it doesn't appear in its "runtime" API.

This smells to me. It implies any further addition to the type hierarchy requires all parents to also represent the added type in its generic declaration.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: wouldn't it be enough to have `interface Group<P extends Person<?>>` ?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to call `getDomain()` then...

Comment: the following works: https://gist.github.com/odolha/8c140ee1c11059a0e146c37b2d9b7beb - isn't this your use case? I just think you need to change `Group<? extends PeopleyPerson<EmailAddress>>` to `Group<PeopleyPerson<EmailAddress>`

Comment: You're correct, convert it to an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough to have

```
interface Group<P extends Person<?>>
```

and then define the actual group instance using concrete types in the hierarchy of composition:

```
Group<PeopleyPerson<EmailAddress>> group
```

This way the consumer of the API will have type safety on the types used while maintaining each interface in the hierarchy (e.g. Group, Person, Address) agnostic of types beyond their immediate children.

See an example of such an implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/odolha/8c140ee1c11059a0e146c37b2d9b7beb)